# Why can't I run more than one thread at a time?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot

I have a spring boot app where I am trying to read multiple readers and then do certain database actions based on what the reader output.  It was working fine until I made the class where it was running a component. Now I am getting an arrayindexoutofboundsexception.  Here's the code.

**Method with error:**

```
private void Start() throws AlienReaderException, IOException{
    ThreadStop = false;

     service= new MessageListenerService(3900);
     service.setMessageListener(this);
     service.startService();
    System.out.println("length of readers: "+Reader.ipAddress.length);

      for (lastThreadId = 0; lastThreadId < Reader.ipAddress.length; 
lastThreadId++)
      {
          **m_inventory[lastThreadId] = new 
AlienReader(Reader.ipAddress[lastThreadId], Reader.port, 
Reader.username[lastThreadId], Reader.password[lastThreadId]);**
          log.info("taginventory reader: "+ 
Reader.ipAddress[lastThreadId]+"Thread: "+lastThreadId);
          m_run_process[lastThreadId] = new Thread(new 
StartInventoryThread(Reader.ipAddress[lastThreadId], Reader.port, 
Reader.username[lastThreadId], Reader.password[lastThreadId], 
m_inventory[lastThreadId]));
          m_run_process[lastThreadId].start();
      }
      --lastThreadId;

      try
      {
          Thread.sleep(1000);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          ex.getMessage();
      }


}
```

**Reader file**

```
public class Reader{

    public static String[] ipAddress={"111.111.11.111", 
        "111.111.11.111","111.111.11.111"};
    public static int port=11;
    public static String[] username={"username", "username"};
    public static String[] password={"password", "password"};
}
```

**Error:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tagInventory' defined in file [C:\Users\rcollins\Workspaces\MyEclipse 2017 CI\rfidreader\target\classes\com\rfidreader\rfidbusiness\TagInventory.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.rfidreader.rfidbusiness.TagInventory]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1238) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1137) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.rfidreader.RfidreaderApplication.main(RfidreaderApplication.java:27) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.rfidreader.rfidbusiness.TagInventory]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:182) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1230) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at com.rfidreader.rfidbusiness.TagInventory.Start(TagInventory.java:139) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.rfidreader.rfidbusiness.TagInventory.<init>(TagInventory.java:96) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:170) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Comment: It's not reasonable to expect someone to read through a 380 line class to solve your problem without additional information. Can you please provide more information about the error, including the stacktrace with line numbers. If possible try to limit the code you are asking people to read and understand to only be the code relevant to the error you're trying to solve

Comment: Is there a reason you are attempting to manage the threads yourself? Unless you have a restriction I'd HIGHLY suggest you not attempt to manage this yourself and instead use some of the high-level concurrency abstractions available in Java. For reference: https://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/07/java8-concurrency-tutorial-thread-executor-examples/

Comment: edited code and added stacktrace

Comment: First: Rule number one of multithreading programming is do not use multithreading unless you have a very good, concrete and demonstrable reason for it, because it is very, very easy to screw it up. I say this as a developer who has been working intensively with multithreading and transactional systems for more than 13 years.

Second: You are iterating with the same for index over 4 different arrays, which haven't been initialized with the same sizes. So if you try to access username[2] or password[2] you will have an indexOutOfBoundException.

Comment: Ok I see the mistake.  I added the username and password for the 3rd position in the array. Thanks!

Comment: OK so no error but I am only getting info from the last thread....no info from the other 2.  What could be the issue?